# Write a file keeping tabs and EOL

Tags: node.js, raml

I am trying to write the content of a string in a file in node.js

I have some raml files and I am able to join them. If I print the variable in console, I see it well parsed but as soon as I save in on a file, the file just contains one single line:

```
var raml = require('raml-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var os = require('os')

path.join(__dirname, './')


raml.loadFile('schema.raml').then( function(data) {
 console.log(data);
  var filePath = "schema.raml"; 
  fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
  fs.writeFile("./new.raml", JSON.stringify(data).replace('/\n', os.EOL),     function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 


}, function(error) {
  console.log('Error parsing: ' + error);
    });
```

I added a replace EOL to change all "\n" in file. If I delete that, file will contain "\n" in each end of line.

On console, this is the output:

```
{ title: 'RAML Flattener',
  baseUri: 'http://github.com/joeledwards/node-flat-raml',
  version: '1',
  mediaType: 'application/json',
  protocols: [ 'HTTP' ],
  resources: 
   [ { relativeUri: '/base',
       methods: [Object],
       resources: [Object],
       relativeUriPathSegments: [Object] } ] }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` is a Javascript object; how that is being displayed when you `console.log()` it doesn't have much to do with how it will end up in the file you are writing.

The problem is that you are using `JSON.stringify()`, which, by default, will not pretty-print the output string.

Instead, try this:

```
JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
```

This will make your output look like this:

```
{
  "title": "RAML Flattener",
  "baseUri": "http://github.com/joeledwards/node-flat-raml",
  "version": "1",
  "mediaType": "application/json",
  "protocols": [
    "HTTP"
  ],
  "resources": [
    {
      "relativeUri": "/base",
      "methods": { ... },
      "resources": { ... },
      "relativeUriPathSegments": { ... }
    }
  ]
}
```

You may or may not need to call `.replace()` on its output. If you do, use this (the one you're using isn't valid):

```
.replace(/\n/, os.EOL)
```